# How to Solve a Divisibility Problem : Prove or disprove

Tags: elementary-number-theory

```
**For all integers a,b,c, prove or disprove each of the following:
i.  If a | c and b | c, then ab | c^2.
ii. If a | (b+c), then a | b and a | c.**
```

Note : "If true prove without using numbers as an example otherwise you can use them if false"
That's What My Prof. says.

Unfortunately, The first one I couldn't solve it but the second one i solve it but i want to ensure that my answers are right 
Thank you in advance

Comment: **Hint:** Remember that the definition of $a\mid c$ is that $c$ is an integer multiple of $a$, in other words there exists some integer $n$ such that $c=a\cdot n$ (*remember, $n$ may be different than another factor that appears from another definition such as for $b\mid c$*).  Show that $c^2$ is an integer multiple of $ab$.

Comment: "*But the second one i solve it*" And your answer there was?  I can't confirm your answer as correct or incorrect since you did not share.

Comment: ii. 25/(3+2) = 5 : a = 3 , b = 2 but 25∤2, 25∤3
∴ If a | (b+c),then a | b and a | c statement is False
@JMoravitz

Comment: $5$ is not a multiple of $25$... it is the other way around.  $25$ is a multiple of $5$.  If $a\mid b$ then $b$ is an integer multiple of $a$.  $5\mid 25$ is true.  $25\mid 5$ is false.

Comment: ii.∵ 5/(13+17) = 6 : a = 13 , b = 17 but 5∤13, 5∤17
∴ If a | (b+c),then a | b and a | c statement is False ,
Is it correct now ? @JMoravitz

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  A much smaller example would have sufficed... $2\mid (1+1)$ but $2\nmid 1$ as well as $2\nmid 1$.