# How to Solve a Divisibility Problem : Prove or disprove (Continued)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**For all integers a,b,c, prove or disprove each of the following:**

**i.  If a | c and b | c, then ab | c^2.**

**ii. If a | (b+c), then a | b and a | c.**

Note : "If true prove without using numbers as an example otherwise you can use them if false" That's What My Prof. says.

Unfortunately, The first one I couldn't solve it.

Note No. 2 : My Question is different than this Question :
[$a\mid b,\ c\mid d\,\Rightarrow\ ac\mid bd $ $\ \, \bf\small [Divisibility\ Product\ Rule]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40118/a-mid-b-c-mid-d-rightarrow-ac-mid-bd-bf-small-divisibility-prod)

Please help me , I didn't understand the question really

Thank you in advance

Comment: For the record, [this was asked by you just recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613113/how-to-solve-a-divisibility-problem-prove-or-disprove?noredirect=1#comment7426855_3613113).  It is better to continue the conversation on your closed posts than opening new identical posts.

Comment: Thank you for advising me , every day I learn new things here :) @JMoravitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not different than the one you mentioned, because your question is a particular case of it, with $b=d$.

Comment: I don't know how to extract what is equivalent to my case really. @Scientifica

Comment: I mentioned it because someone hide my question. @Scientifica

Comment: I ask this question because it is difficult for me , The person (who closed or hide my question I don't know what happened) mentioned The linked Question that is complicated for me ) so how can I understand the second Question If I didn't understand the first one ??  @Scientifica

Comment: @JimHenry Let's use colors then... if $\color{blue}{a}\mid \color{green}{c}$ and $\color{red}{b}\mid \color{purple}{c}$ then $\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{b}\mid \color{green}{c}\color{purple}{c}$.  Just as how  if $\color{blue}{a}\mid \color{green}{b}$ and $\color{red}{c}\mid \color{purple}{d}$ then $\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{c}\mid \color{green}{b}\color{purple}{d}$

Comment: "*It is too complicated for me*" I'm sorry you feel that way, but to continue you really must understand this proof and others like it.  This is just applying the definitions... as I suggested in the previous time you asked this, maybe you should use a more tactile definition of divisibility utilizing the definition that $a\mid c$ if and only if there exists some integer $n$ such that $c = n\cdot a$.  Note that if $c=na$ as well as $c=mb$ for some integers $m,n$ then what does $c^2$ equal?  Is it an integer multiple of $ab$?

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now @JMoravitz

Comment: @JimHenry I just came in and saw JMoravitz' great answers with colors, as well as good explanation of the proof. Glad you understood.

Comment: Okay, I will practice it again , Thanks you very much:) @JMoravitz